# Unable to install python packages - Could not found suitable TLS certificate bundle

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, anaconda, ssl-certificate, jupyter-notebook

I am struggling to make Python (Anaconda) work from last few days. I had tried installing pytorch few days back and it crashed in between. Hence forth, my Anaconda is giving errors while installing any packages. I have Windows 10, 64 bit user with Python 3.6.1. - Intel chipset.
[image]
I am unable to install any package - above is the issue.

I even tried uninstalling and installing Anaconda which is the only Python distribution I have on my machine.

Another error which I receive -
[image]

[image]

Any help in this matter would be of great great help!!

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade pip as follows:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Note: You may need to use  `sudo python` above if not in a virtual environment.

(Note that upgrading `pip` using `pip` i.e `pip install --upgrade pip` will also not upgrade it correctly. `pip` won't work unless using TLS >= 1.2.)

**For PyCharm (virtualenv) users:**

Run virtual environment with shell. (replace "./venv/bin/activate" to your own path)

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Run upgrade

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Restart your PyCharm instance, and check your Python interpreter in Preference.